# Drop down list not in center

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, text-alignment

im currently working on a website. i have a drop down list on my header menu and it is working, but it is not in the center of the link above. how can i set it so that it drops down right at middle of the hovering text?

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSbsm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property to the dropdown

```
 {
  left:-1rem;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```